# Freeing dynamically allocated memory in a tree

Tags: c, memory, gcc, malloc, free

I'm trying to free memory that I allocated with malloc, but free is giving the error:

```
 malloc: *** error for object 0x100100800: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap
```

I have a tree with nodes

```
struct node {
  struct state *s;
  struct node *child;
  struct node *sibling;
};
```

and I am trying to free all nodes except for one child and its decedents with this function:

```
struct node * free_children (struct node *head, struct node *keep_c) {
  struct stack_node *stack_head = init_stack();
  struct node *popped;
  push(stack_head, head);
  // to avoid checking if = keep_c for each level, do top level first
  for (struct node * s = head->child; s != 0; s = s->sibling) {
    if (s != keep_c) push(stack_head, s);
  }
  while (!stack_is_empty(stack_head)) {
    popped = pop(stack_head);
    if (popped->child != 0) push(stack_head, popped->child);
    if (popped->sibling != 0) push(stack_head, popped->sibling);
    free(popped->s);
  }
  return keep_c;
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what's going on, as all nodes were created with malloc, as were all the states pointed to by the nodes.

Edit: Here's the code allocating memory:

```
void push (struct stack_node *head, struct node *k) {
  struct stack_node * x = (struct stack_node *)
    malloc(sizeof(struct stack_node));
  x->key = k;
  x->next = head->next;
  head->next = x;
  return;
}

struct stack_node * init_stack () {
  struct stack_node * head = (struct stack_node *)
    malloc(sizeof(struct stack_node));
  head->next = 0;
  return head;
}

struct node * build_game_tree (int p1, int p2) {
  struct node *head = init_game_tree();
  struct state *state = (struct state *) malloc(sizeof(struct state));
  state->player = 0;
  state->s[0] = p1; state->s[1] = p2;
  head->s = state;
  struct stack_node *stack_head = init_stack();
  struct stack_node *upper_stack_head = init_stack();
  struct node *popped;
  bool possible_moves[9];
  push(stack_head, head);
  while(!stack_is_empty(stack_head)) {
    popped = pop(stack_head);
    if (!endgame(popped->s->s[0], popped->s->s[1])) {
      push_possible_moves(stack_head, popped);
      push(upper_stack_head, popped);
    }
    else {
      popped->child = 0;
      popped->s->score =
        score(popped->s->s[0], popped->s->s[1]);
    }
  }
  ...
  return head;
}
```

Edit:

```
struct state {
  unsigned int s[2];
  double score;
  unsigned int player;
};
```

Comment: You need to show us some more code, at least where the allocation happens

Comment: Do you know how to write a minimal, compilable testcase? Remove any code that isn't necessary to demonstrate the problem. If your code requires user, socket or file input, replace that logic with string copying into the variables. The idea is to give us a compilable demonstration of your problem that is under fifty lines in length.

Comment: Where's the definition of `struct state`? Is `state->s` a pointer, or a fixed-size array?

Comment: "I'm having trouble figuring out what's going on" Try printing the address of everything you allocate and everything you free.

Comment: Hi Jim, I've updated with the def of `struct state`. Printing the address of allocation is a good idea, thanks. Will try that and report back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `free_children()`, you attempt to free the same memory more than once. The `for` loop starts with the first child, and iterates over all of the child's siblings, putting them onto the stack. The while loop also iterates over each child's siblings, also putting them onto the stack. Whenever a node appears on the stack, you eventually attempt to `free()` it.

You need to rethink the structure of `free_children()`. It might be easier to start with a recursive implementation, optionally later converting it into an iterative one if there is a compelling need.